# URL sometimes not being properly encoded - threading issue?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am working on a Windows Form application in C# and have a method like the following which is being accessed by multiple threads (precisely, by multiple background workers):

```
public Uri signURL(OAuthToken token, string url)
{
   UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(addOAuthParameters(url));
   NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);

   query.Set("oauth_consumer_key", consumerKey);

   /*
    * & sometimes not replaced by %26
    */
   query.Set("oauth_signature", consumerSecret + "&" + token.Secret);
   query.Set("oauth_token", token.Token);
   builder.Query = query.ToString();

   return builder.Uri;
}
```

I use this method to sign an arbitrary URL with some required OAuth parameters and afterwards do an HttpWebRequest to retrieve the content.

**Edit 1:** Here is the content of the addOAuthParameter method:

```
private Uri addOAuthParameters(string uri)
{
    UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(uri);
    NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(builder.Query);
    query.Set("oauth_signature_method", "PLAINTEXT");
    query.Set("oauth_timestamp", "" + (int)(DateTime.UtcNow -
        new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds);
    query.Set("oauth_nonce", "" + getNonce());
    query.Set("oauth_version", "1.0");
    builder.Query = query.ToString();
    return builder.Uri;
}
```

Sometimes, the oauth_signature parameter contains an ampersand although this should be properly encoded with %26 by the NameValueCollection object, and, as result, I get a "401 Unauthorized". I have the feeling this happens when the method is being accessed by multiple background workers (multiple threads?). Is that possible?

**Edit 2:** Okay, it seems that I've narrowed down the issue. If I do a `Debug.Assert(builder.Uri.ToString().Contain("%26") && builder.Uri.PathAndQuery.Contains("%26"));` it turns out that `builder.Uri.ToString()` does not contain the %26 while `builder.Uri.PathAndQuery` does. Now, why's that?

Debugging the issue turned out to be very hard. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: No, that isn't threading. The only objects being mutated are local to that method invocation; they do not appear to be shared between threads (for example, via a field, or a mutable class parameter).

Comment: What's about consumerKey and consumerSecret? Are these edited by other threads/in other functions?
EDIT: Could you please let us have a look at your addOAuthParameters(string) function?

Comment: consumerKey and consumerSecret are local to the object containing the method and are never modified from outside (they are private). I'll give you the addOAuthParameters tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Uri.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.tostring.aspx) is for display only the docs state that it returns an un-escaped string.

You want to use [Uri.AbsoluteUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absoluteuri.aspx), [Uri.OriginalString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.originalstring.aspx) or [Uri.GetComponents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getcomponents.aspx).

```
var uri = new Uri("http://example.com/some?query=testing%26other");
Console.WriteLine(uri.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.AbsoluteUri, UriFormat.UriEscaped));

http://example.com/some?query=testing&other
/some?query=testing%26other
```

GetComponents has the advantage that the escaping is explicitly specified so there's no ambiguity.

Some simple advice (originally from Keith Brown's blog post, [Beware Uri.ToString](http://web.archive.org/web/20100317150921/http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/keith/archive/2009/10/10/beware-uri-tostring.aspx)).

- Use Uri.AbsoluteUri to get the value of a URI when you know it’s absolute.
- Use Uri.OriginalString to get the value of a URI when it could be either absolute or relative (this method does not throw an InvalidOperationException for a relative URI).
- Use Uri.ToString to get the value of a URI only when you really want it to be unescaped (e.g. when you want to display it nicely for a human).
- When viewing a URI in the debugger, remember the debugger uses Uri.ToString so what you see may not match exactly what the URI contains.

Comment: Brilliant, that pretty much nailed it. The Uri interface is really confusing. Thank you very much Sir!